# FTP using nodejs- FTP Json object to another machine using nodejs and save the object json on recieving machine

Tags: node.js, json

I want to FTP encrypted JSON object from Nodejs to another machine and save it there at one constant location(directory) in as json file. ftped object should be stored as json file at receiving machine

How can this be done using nodejs?